# Struct and pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to print the value pointed by a pointer who is himself pointed by a pointer.

I have 2 structs

```
typedef struct s_thread_police
{
    l_hash *lhash;
    // other stuff for thread purpose
} thread_police_arg;

typedef struct s_l_hash
{
    struct s_l_hash* next;
    char* hash;
} *l_hash;
```

How do I print the hash of the struct I point to?

```
police_arg.lhash = &lhash;
printf("%s\n", *(police_arg.lhash)->hash);
```

The compiler is telling me "error: request for member ‘hash’ in something not a structure or union"

I have try some other way but none of them are working
Thx for your help

Comment: You try to print something called `hash` but it is not defined in the code you've shown!

Comment: I have fixed it in edit.

Comment: Please provide an actual [mcve] that is compilable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
printf("%s\n", (*police_arg.lhash)->hash);
```

`*police_arg.lhash` gives you an `l_hash`, which is a pointer to a `s_l_hash` which you then dereference to get `hash`.

Comment: Thx it's exactly that. I was confuse about the implicit ()